# ASP.NET Core 6+, Autofac, TreeRouteBuilder costructor not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I'm migrating from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to ASP.NET Core 8, and I have this problem.

To keep the code changes as minimum as possible, I'm using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()` passing a `Startup` class.

In this, I'm using a `ConfigureServices` that returns an `AutofacServiceProvider` with a `ILifetimeScope` object. I use the classic `AddMvc`/`UseMvc` (with the endpoints disabled). I've removed all the old NuGet packages and created SDK style `.csproj` with the ".web" suffix or added the `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`.

Trying to test it, I get an error when in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing` is called the `GetTreeRouter()` function, I get:

> Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException : No constructors on type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouteBuilder' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'.

In the code, the `TreeRouteBuilder` seems internal, so it's normal the DI is not capable of finding the constructor. I've forgotten to update something essential to work?

EDIT:
I've changed the `AddMvc` and `UseMvc` with more modern `AddControllersWithViews` and `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`, I get this exception

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An exception was thrown while activating Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.MatcherPolicy[] -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.DynamicControllerEndpointMatcherPolicy.
> Data:
> ActivatorChain: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.MatcherPolicy[] -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.DynamicControllerEndpointMatcherPolicy
> ----> Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException : No constructors on type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.EndpointMetadataComparer' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'.

Also this constructor is an internal one. I'm start to think that I'm having something wrong that doesn't register the ASP.NET Core to the Autofac container. I return the `IServicesProvider` in `ConfigureServices`, need to check if this is still possible or not possible in ASP.NET Core 8

Comment: If I had to guess, you haven't got all the stuff set up right post-migration. I might recommend doing a `dotnet new` to get a default web app and then start using a diff tool to figure out the changes. For example, you shouldn't have that `<FrameworkReference>` in your web app, it's automatically assumed in .NET 8. I think you're going to have a lot of weird problems jumping so far forward without doing that diff. A lot has changed since back then.

Comment: Have you check this: https://docs.autofac.org/en/v6.0.0/troubleshooting/exceptions/no-found-constructors.html  ?  Have a look at the component (class) noted in the exception and see if there are any constructors.

Comment: I've already tried to do a new project, but it uses the the minimal host paradigm, and I have too much code that relies on the startup class to do this. In Microsoft documentation, Generic Hosting is still supported, so this is why I'm going this way.

Comment: I've checked the Autofac documentation. The trouble is: the constructor is in a Microsoft library, not an user writable one. So the trouble is not why the constructor is not available, is why I'm calling it: it should not be called to work

Comment: Forgot to mention: I need the <FrameworkReference> in projects that manages the web server but are not Web application per se: if not using the element, I would get a missing assembly exception. Web application have only the ".web" suffix